# Transforming a .csv file in R

Tags: r, csv

I have a following `.csv` file that I downloaded online:

```
financials.morningstar.com/ajax/exportKR2CSV.html?&t=AAPL
```

I am trying to edit the spreadsheet so that the column names are dates and row names are the various ratios and indices provided in it. Below is my code, but neither column nor row names work. Any suggestions?

```
read.csv('/path_to_csv.csv',header=F)[-c(1:2),-c(12)]->spreadsheet
spreadsheet_body<-spreadsheet[-1,-1]
colnames(spreadsheet_body)<-spreadsheet[1,-1]
rownames(spreadsheet_body)<-c()
rownames(spreadsheet_body)<-spreadsheet[-1,1]
```

Comment: If you add column names before making `spreadsheet_body` you can add  your column names with just `spreadsheet[1,]`, and you'll get the right values. Row names are harder because you have duplicate values under "Key Ratios -> Growth"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider simply transposing the data frame with [t()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/t.html) and then replacing the headers from first row. Below uses the AAPL csv file from URL:

```
df <- read.csv('http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/exportKR2CSV.html?&t=AAPL', 
           skip=2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df <- df[df[2]!='2006-09',]               # REMOVE REPEAT HEADERS
df <- df[-grep('Key Ratios', df$X),]      # REMOVE KEY RATIO HEADERS

finaldf <- data.frame(t(df), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(finaldf) <- finaldf[1,]
finaldf <- finaldf[-1,]

# PERIOD COLUMN
finaldf$Period <- as.character(rownames(finaldf))
finaldf$Period <- gsub("X", "Y", gsub("\\.", "M", finaldf$Period))

rownames(finaldf) <- 1:nrow(finaldf)                      # RESET ROWNAMES
finaldf <- finaldf[,c(ncol(finaldf), 2:ncol(finaldf)-1)]  # RE-ORDER PERIOD TO START

# CONVERT TO NUMERIC
for (i in names(finaldf)) {
        if (i != "Period") {
          finaldf[[i]] <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", finaldf[[i]]))
        }
     }

finaldf[, c(1:7)]
```

**Output**

```
#      Period Revenue USD Mil Gross Margin % Operating Income USD Mil
# 1  Y2006M09           19315           29.0                     2453
# 2  Y2007M09           24006           34.0                     4409
# 3  Y2008M09           32479           34.3                     6275
# 4  Y2009M09           42905           40.1                    11740
# 5  Y2010M09           65225           39.4                    18385
# 6  Y2011M09          108249           40.5                    33790
# 7  Y2012M09          156508           43.9                    55241
# 8  Y2013M09          170910           37.6                    48999
# 9  Y2014M09          182795           38.6                    52503
# 10 Y2015M09          233715           40.1                    71230
# 11      TTM          227535           39.8                    66864
#    Operating Margin % Net Income USD Mil Earnings Per Share USD
# 1                12.7               1989                   0.32
# 2                18.4               3496                   0.56
# 3                19.3               4834                   0.77
# 4                27.4               8235                   1.30
# 5                28.2              14013                   2.16
# 6                31.2              25922                   3.95
# 7                35.3              41733                   6.31
# 8                28.7              37037                   5.68
# 9                28.7              39510                   6.45
# 10               30.5              53394                   9.22
# 11               29.4              50678                   8.97
```

Comment: it looks almost perfect, but is there a way to avoid deforming dates into `X2007.06` format, but instead keep it intact so that I can format it into real dates?

Comment: Couple of things: *X* is placed because R does not allow columns to start with numbers. And the transpose kept that naming. Second, the column is not a complete date format since report header had no day number. Plus the *TTM* to consider.

Comment: See update where I add a Period column replacing X and decimal, and even convert all the character columns to numeric.

Answer (score 2):

This does not solve all the questions, but you could try the `rownames` by parts:

```
read.csv("http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/exportKR2CSV.html?&t=AAPL",header=T,stringsAsFactors = F,skip = 2)[,-c(12)]->spreadsheet
#str(spreadsheet)
View(spreadsheet)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't give the specific message. When I run your code I get

```
duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique values when setting 'row.names': ‘’, ‘10-Year Average’, ‘3-Year  Average’, ‘
```

I suspect this occurs because the name 3-Year Average etc. occur in many sections.

Here is a possible approach (for only three of the sections) that is tedious, but may make subsequent processing easier .

```
financials <- read.table('Downloads/AAPL Key Ratios.csv',sep=",",quote = '"', skip=3, nrow=15,
                         col.names=c('item', 'Y2006M09',    'Y2007M09',     'Y2008M09',     'Y2009M09', 'Y2010M09', 
                                     'Y2011M09',    'Y2012M09', 'Y2013M09', 'Y2014M09', 'Y2015M09', 'TTM'))
margins    <- read.table('Downloads/AAPL Key Ratios.csv',sep=",",quote = '"', skip=21, nrow=9,  
                         col.names=c('item', 'Y2006M09',    'Y2007M09',     'Y2008M09',     'Y2009M09', 'Y2010M09', 
                                     'Y2011M09',    'Y2012M09', 'Y2013M09', 'Y2014M09', 'Y2015M09', 'TTM'))
revenue_percent <- read.table('Downloads/AAPL Key Ratios.csv',sep=",",quote = '"', skip=44, nrow=4,  
                         col.names=c('item', 'Y2006M09',    'Y2007M09',     'Y2008M09',     'Y2009M09', 'Y2010M09', 
                                     'Y2011M09',    'Y2012M09', 'Y2013M09', 'Y2014M09', 'Y2015M09', 'TTM'))
```